# When is could too repetitive?

Tags: grammar

I am having trouble figuring out when to use the word, could.

For example, in the sentence "There is a possibility that person had hit my car". If I used "could have" instead of "had", I think it would be repetitive.

But in the sentence, "There is a possibility I could have done better". Without the could the sentence meaning changes.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with "There is a possibility that person could have hit my car".

Comment: Arvin, please take a look at English Language Learners, our sister site, if you haven't already.  I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: How can *there is a possibility that a person could have hit my car* be repetitive when *could* is only used once? Repetition requires that something be used at least twice. Whether it's *too* repetitive is a matter of opinion, but that a single use is not repetitive at all is an objective fact.

Comment: If you're talking about *could* being the equivalent to *possibility*, and therefore repeating a concept rather than a word, that's a matter of opinion. In the sentence in question, *had* and *could have* mean different things, and using one over the other when you don't mean it would be to say something other than what you mean. In short, I think it's only repetitive in a kind of artificially constructed way of analyzing it, and I certainly don't feel as if it's *too* repetitive.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, swapping "had" for "could have" would change the meaning of the sentence.

"There is a possibility that person had hit my car". Means: your car was hit (by someone), and it is possible that it was "that person".

"There is a possibility that person could have hit my car". Means: your car was not hit, but if the conditions were different, then "that person" might have bumped into it.

Comment: I'm not sure that this precisionist interpretation matches how many people actually use the language.

Answer (score -1):

If you use "could have" instead of "had", then this is repetitive.

"Could" means something that you believe is likely to be true or to happen, the sentence has already have "there is a possibility" in the beginning and there is no need to use "could".